# What is a CPU soft lockup?

Tags: linux, kernel, cpu

I like to know, What is a CPU soft lockup? and possible causes, I can only tell you that was presented in a server based on RedHat Linux with the message **Kernel Bug**. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 5):

**I found the response...**

A soft lockup is the symptom of a task or kernel thread using and not releasing a CPU for a period of time.

The technical reason behind a soft lock involves CPU interrupts and nmiwatchdog. For each CPU on the system, a watchdog process gets created. This process “wakes up” once per second, gets the current time stamp for the CPU it is responsible for, and saves this into the CPU data structure.

**Regards!**

Comment: Is there any tool for identify soft lock occurring in my system or not if yes then what happen next.?

Comment: @AnkurLoriya If you `dmesg`, you will see the relevant messages.